# TTS read from twitter android

Tags: android, twitter, text-to-speech

Have an app that can use tts to read text messages.  It can also allow login to twitter and post to the news field.  Interested in possibly fetching data from the news feed and reading this out aswell, similar to the sms functionality I already have in place.

Have not seen any source or tutorials for this, other than an appinventor project that seems to do what I would like!
Anyone offer ideas how I might go about getting something like this working in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a client to read Tweets as explained here:
http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/02/15/twitter-android/

And to read the news just use this class android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech

Comment: Hi, thanks for link.  I downloaded the sample source code to check it out.  It compiles fine, but when I deploy to device it gives an instant force close error.  Can't see any particular problems with the code.

Comment: Have you check the Logcat? If it crashs you should be able to see the error log.

Comment: I have just install on my phone.Import the project to Eclipse and I fixed 2 errors with the strings. But I can use it. Check the Android Manifest, as it seems you need to allow the service to execute.

Comment: Check the android manifest for what?  I fix the string errors too, and it compiles fine, but still crashes while eclipse exports to phone.  Maybe it's a problem with my phone... hmm EDIT: same problem with emulator too.  Building for android 2.1 by the way.

Comment: Why doesnt work? Anyway the project can serve to u as a foundation for your future project. Its important to understand it very well...

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. It does not crash, just wont post to twitter.